# Elementary computation of series involving zeta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

Is there a simple way to prove the following identity

$$\sum_{s=2}^{\infty}(\zeta(s)-1)=1$$

I imagine that there is some nice thing one can do using the Euler product representation, though it currently escapes me.

EDIT:

I can show that this is equal to

$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{12}+\dots=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2+n}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{s=2}^{\infty} (\zeta(s)-1) = \sum\limits_{s=2}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^s} = \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{s=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^s} = \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(k-1)}$$

$$=  \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k} $$

This last sum is telescoping.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured this out and was about to post it!

Comment: I always figure things out right after I post them on stackexchange